# Why does Go use less memory for a slice of length 100k, than for an array of length 100k?

Tags: arrays, go, heap-memory, stack-memory

Consider the following code where I allocate 4 thousand arrays, each of length 100k:

```
    parentMap := make(map[int][100_000]int)
    for i := 0; i < 4000; i++ {
        parentMap[i] = [100_000]int{}
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Millisecond)
    }
```

If I run that locally, and analyze its memory usage, it starts to use >2GB of memory.

Now, if we changed the code slightly to use a slices of arrays (but also of length 100k) like so:

```
    parentMap := make(map[int][]int)
    for i := 0; i < 4000; i++ {
        parentMap[i] = make([]int, 100_000)
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Millisecond)
    }
```

On my machine, memory peaks at about 73MB. **Why is this?**

I thought that both of these snippets would use roughly equal memory with the following reasoning:

- In both cases, the Go runtime will allocate the values of `parentMap` on the heap. Go does this because if it allocated these values on the stack, then the values of `parentMap` would all clear as soon as the current function went out of scope.
- Therefore the first snippet allocates 4k arrays directly on the heap.
- And, the second snippet allocates 4k slice headers on the heap. Each slice header has a pointer to a unique array (also on the heap) of size 100k.
- In both cases, there are 4k arrays on the heap of size 100k. And therefore, roughly equal amount of memory should be used in either case.

I read: https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro. But couldn't find an implementation detail that explains this.

Comment: Arrays are values, and you are copying each one into the map. Slices only contain a pointer to the underlying array.

Comment: correct. but the underlying array of a slice (allocated on the heap), must take up just as much memory as an array that is used directly as a value; this is why I am confused

Comment: Both examples show roughly the same total allocation on my system. You are probably looking at the OS reported usage which isn't taking into account unused pages.

Comment: How are you checking? The results above I got from Activity Monitor on MacOS. But I just checked on pprof and I got similar results (1.05GB first snippet, 512kb second)

Comment: The runtime memory stats will show you exactly what is allocated by the runtime. The array version also shows 199876 page reclaims vs 3829 for the slices in the OS, the OS just isn't reporting the memory you haven't used. Write 0s to the slices and see what happens.

Comment: 1. "Golang": The name of the language is "Go". 2. "the Go[...] runtime will allocate the values of parentMap on the heap. Gol[...] does this because if it allocated these values on the stack" is formally wrong as Go the programming language as specified has no notion of "heap" and "stack". Both concepts are implementation details of (some) of the compilers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version with the slices is probably benefiting from lazy allocation. Nothing ever tries to write to the data buffer of one of those slices, so the OS is free to not actually allocate the memory for those buffers until something actually tries to write. (The OS can zero-initialize the buffers lazily too, so that doesn't force an allocation.)

Meanwhile, the version with the arrays needs to actually copy the arrays into the map, and that means actually performing writes. Even though the values written are all zeros, they're still writes, so the OS has to actually allocate memory for the data to be written to.

Try writing data to those slices, and the slice version should take gigabytes of memory too. (I think one value per page of memory should be enough, but it may be easier to just fill the slices with `1`s.)

Comment: i think you're right, i added a loop to the version with slices, filling it with 0s and the memory went up to be GBs as well, according to Activity Monitor. thank you!